# Why didn't I get the populist badge?

Tags: support, badges, populist-badge

I see there are [some questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/populist) about populist badge, but in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7985872/splitting-a-6-digit-integer-in-c-sharp/7985905#7985905) case, I have all the criteria for populist badge, I have highest score among all answers, I outscored the accepted answer more than 2 times and more than +10, even I was a first one to answer, but still I didn't get the populist badge.

P.S: This answer as you can see was for some years ago, today I see the [gold badges](https://stackoverflow.com/badges?tab=general&filter=gold) and I was wondering why I didn't get it yet.

Comment: It's an odd rule. I have a similar case here, where [the selected answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5257607/597607) would need 13 upvotes for me to get the badge. (Current votes -2 vs 32 :-)

Comment: @BoPersson, quite interesting :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Highest scoring answer that outscored **an accepted answer with score of more than 10** by more than 2x

The accepted answer in that case does not have a score of more than 10. In other words the accepted answer must have at least a score of 11 and your answer at least a score of 23.

Comment: OK I thought my answer should have more than 10 score than accepted answer, really bad definition, I think should be edited. thanks.

Comment: Yes, I think a few commas in that sentance wouldn't hurt.